# find pattern on multiline python

Tags: python, regex

I spent two days tried to build regular expression to find two words/numbers occur Sequentially on different lines.
I has a file that has text like:

```
  1  [pid 29743] 18:58:19 prctl(PR_CAPBSET_DROP, 0x9, 0, 0, 0 <unfinished ...>
  2  [pid 29746] 18:58:19 <... mprotect resumed> ) = 0
  3  [pid 29743] 18:58:19 <... prctl resumed> ) = 0
  4  [pid   615] 18:58:19 <... ioctl resumed> , 0xffffffffffb4f054) = 0
  5  [pid 29743] 18:58:19 prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0xa, 0, 0, 0 <unfinished ...>
  6  [pid   615] 18:58:19 ioctl(13, 0x40047703 <unfinished ...>
  7  [pid 29743] 18:58:19 <... prctl resumed> ) = 1
  8  [pid 29746] 18:58:19 mprotect(0xfffffffff4ae2000, 4096, PROT_NONE <unfinished ...>
  9  [pid 29743] 18:58:19 prctl(PR_CAPBSET_DROP, 0xa, 0, 0, 0 <unfinished ...>
  10 [pid   615] 18:58:19 <... ioctl resumed> , 0x7fd19062e0) = 0
  11 [pid 29743] 18:58:19 <... prctl resumed> ) = 0
  12 [pid 29746] 18:58:19 <... mprotect resumed> ) = 0
  13 [pid 29743] 18:58:19 prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0xb, 0, 0, 0 <unfinished ...>
  14 [pid 29746] 18:58:19 ioctl(13, 0x40047703, 
  <unfinished ...>
  15 [pid 29743] 18:58:19 <... prctl resumed> ) = 1
  16 [pid   615] 18:58:19 <... ioctl resumed> , 0x7fd19064b0) = 0
```

I am looking for two values 0x7fd19062e0 and 0x7fd19064b0 that has appeared Sequentially on text. They have appeared at line 10 and 16. 
I want to build regular expression that tells me if appeared or not Sequentially
 Here is my code

```
    file = open("text.txt", a+)
    for line in file:
        text += line
    if re.findall(r"^.*0x7fd19062e0.*0x7fd19064b0", text, re.M):
                       print 'found a match!'
                    else:
                       print 'no match'
```

Comment: `.`  does not match newlines. The `re.S` modifier would change that behavior, but what exactly do you mean be sequentially?

Comment: what I means by  sequentially is  first I have to see 0x7fd19062e0 
 and then 0x7fd19064b0. sometime  0x7fd19064b0 comes before  0x7fd19062e0 which is not my case here

Answer (score 1):

`re.M` modifies the behavior of `^` and `$` anchors. For the "dot matches newline" option, you need `re.S`. Also, if you just want to find if there is a match, don't use `re.findall()`:

```
file = open("text.txt")  # why append mode?
text = file.read()       # no need to build the string line by line
if re.search(r"\b0x7fd19062e0\b.*\b0x7fd19064b0\b", text, re.S):
     print 'found a match!'
else:
     print 'no match'
```

Note that I added [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) to ensure that only entire hex numbers are matched (otherwise, submatches of longer numbers would be possible). This may or may not be relevant in your case, but it's probably good practice.

Comment: Make it lazy ! As in `...\b.*?\b...` otherwise, you'll overrun another match.

Comment: @Jan: Yes, if there could be more than one match, this gets relevant. That's one reason why I asked for a clarification on what kaloon means by "sequentially".

Answer (score 0):

No need for RE:

```
f = open('text.txt')
numerated_lines = enumerate(f.readlines())
lines_with_pattern = filter(lambda l: '0x7fd19062e0' in l[1], enumerated_lines)
pairs = zip(lines, lines[1:])
result = filter(lambda p: p[0][0]+1 == p[1][0], pairs)
```